# OpenCV: Hough Circles, trouble detecting object

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am a complete beginner when it comes to OpenCV, I have no clue where to start when trying to detect circles of a certain size, below is my current code (not much) along with the image I am trying to detect, if anyone could help me or give me some advice it would be much appreciated, (i have converted image to grayscale and added gaussian blur so it is easier to detect) Thanks!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkaT2.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


test = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img,  5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


cv2.imshow("HoughCirlces",  test)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great work, you're almost there, all you have to do now is actually apply the CHT. The function you are looking for is cv2.HoughCircles(). You need to pass the image, in your case you can use either img or cimg and some parameters that might require tuning. Here is some template code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


test = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img,  5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow("HoughCirlces",  test)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can also take a look at the documentation and tutorial. I'll link them below.
Tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html
Docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d

Comment: Thanks for replying! How do I go about getting the right parameters for the circles? I'm not too sure how to do this.

Comment: you have to tune them yourself to see what params work best for your case
for the 1, you can go from 0.8 to 1.2, still, 1 is the recommended
for the 20 you can go from 5 to 50, but still, depends on the image
etc.

Comment: what did you got when running that? swell, it would be great if it works to mark the answer correct or upvote it :)

Comment: TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type NoneType which has no callable rint method

Comment: I'll test out different things tomorrow, as soon as i get it sorted i will happily upvote :)

Comment: still haven't got anywhere yet haha.. I'll keep trying

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: I finally did it! thanks for your advice, I will upvote